# How to find the derivative with respect to $x^2$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I would like to find the derivative of this function with respect to x^2.

$-0.5\ln({2\pi x^{2}}) - \frac{1}{2 x^{2}}$

The answer I got is:

$-(0.5)(\frac{1}{2\pi x^{2}})(2\pi)(2) - (0.5)(-1)(\frac{1}{x^{4}})(2)$

$=-\frac{1}{x^{2}} + \frac{1}{x^{4}}$

Is it correct?

Comment: How about you include your work in arriving at that conclusion?

Comment: Let $y = x^2$ and then use the usual derivative with respect to $y$.

Comment: You should show all the steps to obtain the result.

Comment: What do you mean by *with respect to $x^2$*? Do you mean your substituting $x^2$ as let’s say $t$ and taking the derivative wrt $t$? Also if you simply want to assert correctness of your answer, use something like this:
https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxL0yjRVLBV0DXUN9LKyU_XMNIqyNQq0QTygcwSTV6ulMy0NI00HYUSTY0S2wotLSNNAEsUDM0=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==

Comment: Why do you multiply by $(2)$? $(x^2)'=2x$

Comment: What does it mean to take the derivative with respect to $x^2$? This is not standard terminology.

Answer (score 1):

If in some problems you are having difficulties then you can use chain rule.

y = $-0.5\ln({2\pi x^{2}}) - \frac{1}{2 x^{2}}$ =  $-0.5ln(2{\pi}) - ln(x) -  \frac{x^{-2}}{2}       $

To find: $\frac{dy}{dx^2}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dx^2}$ = $\frac{dy}{dx}\left({\frac{dx^2}{dx}}\right)^{-1}$ = $(2x)^{-1}\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dx^2}$ = $\frac{1}{2x}$$(-\frac{1}{x}+x^{-3})$

Or Simply:

$-0.5\frac{1}{2\pi{x^2}}2{\pi}$ - $\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{x^4})$ = $-\frac{0.5}{x^2}$ +$\frac{1}{2x^4}$